# image and search filter not getting responsive in all the devices in Xamarine Mobile Application any help leads?

Tags: android, iphone, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the below code in xamarine form UI I wanted that my filter and search icon should fit in all the devices.

Below is the code can someone help me in this to resolve

```
<RelativeLayout Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

<ImageButton HorizontalOptions="En[![enter image description here][1]][1]d" Margin="350,10,0,0" WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="33" Source="refresh_btn" Clicked="img_Refresh_Clicked" x:Name="img_Refresh"></ImageButton>

<Image WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="15" Margin="190, 15"
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Width,
Factor=0,
Constant=130}"
RelativeLayout.YConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Height,
Factor=0,
Constant=0}"
HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Source="ic_arrow_drop_down" Aspect="AspectFit" x:Name="img"
/>
<Picker x:Name="navigationPassengerList" Title="Select Passenger"
RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
ElementName=img,
Property=Width,
Factor=0,
Constant=340}"
RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
ElementName=img,
Property=Height,
Factor=0,
Constant=50}" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Width,
Factor=0,
Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
Property=Height,
Factor=0,
Constant=0}"
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
SelectedIndexChanged="navigationPassengerList_SelectedIndexChanged" Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent"></Picker>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have not explained what problem you are having with this code

Comment: `image and search filter not getting responsive` Sorry,  where exactly did you go wrong? Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: You can see in the attached image search bar and icon not extending to the full width and this happening on different devices. Not working like responsive o full width.

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't see any image.   If it is convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?